# Prevent fade-out of line highlight

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome's developer tools, the console displays clickable links pointing to specific lines in JavaScript source files, such as where an exception was thrown.

Upon clicking such a link, the respective file is automatically opened and the line in question is scrolled into view. Furthermore, this line is highlighted with a yellow background ... for a moment. **This highlighting quickly fades away.** I am working with huge bundled files, and by the time the bundled file is displayed, the highlight sometimes has already completely disappeared.

**How can I prevent this fade-out effect, in order to gain more time to do something with the line while it's still conveniently highlighted?**